# Программа "Date" не изменяет время в системе линукс, как исправить?

Tags: linux, archlinux

Ввожу команду - `$ sudo date -s "2022-06-11 05:30:00"`. В системе время не изменяется. Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo timedatectl set-time "2022-06-11 05:30:00"
```

детальнее как работать с системным временем смотри в [ArchWiki/System time](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_time#System_clock)